# How to resolve UnityContainer and when in windows serivce

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, windows-services, unity-container

I am creating a Windows Service which uses existing class library for application and domain models.

Application layer already have already defined `ContainerConfig` which registers all Interfaces like

```
  public class ConfigContainer
  {
  public UnityContainer ContainerConfig()
     {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IAttachmentService, AttachmentService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IBrxxgeService, BrxxgeService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICaxxxxociationService, CaxxxxociationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());            
        container.RegisterType<ITraxxxacityService, TraxxxcityService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        return container;
    }
}
```

There are more than 30 Service Interfaces registered here like that. in Window Service `Program.cs`

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    { 
        new DClearanceService() 
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

}
```

Then in `DClearanceService.cs`

```
public partial class DClearanceService : ServiceBase
{
    private ConfigContainer _containerConfig = new ConfigContainer();
    private UnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();

    public DimensionalClearanceService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExceptionHandlingManager.InitializeExceptionManager();

        _container = _containerConfig.ContainerConfig();
    }
```

Inside my methods are resolving container:

```
public class EMTrocessor
{
    _clRequestService = Container.Resolve<IClRequestService>();

    public bool ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        List<ClOutput> clOutputs = _clRequestService.GetClOutputs();
    }
 }
```

If I run this code using visual studio in debugger mode, it works fine but when I run this windows service, I get `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException`

```
    <Description>An exception of type 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException' occurred and was caught.</Description>
  <DateTime>2015-11-30 16:53:55Z</DateTime>
  <ExceptionType>Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException, Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f</ExceptionType>
   <Message>Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CPR.Apps.Application.Interfaces.IClEventService", name = "(none)".
  Exception occurred while: Calling constructor CPR.Apps.Application.Services.CleranceEventService().
  Exception is: ResolutionFailedException - Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "CPR.Apps.Domain.Interfaces.IClEventManager", name = "(none)".
    Exception occurred while: while resolving.
   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, CPR.Apps.Domain.Interfaces.IClEventManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
 -----------------------------------------------
 At the time of the exception, the container was:

 Resolving CPR.Apps.Domain.Interfaces.IClEventManager,(none)
```

When I call service, it already resolves the related service and this is how visual studio interact with db and returns the result. Why it can't do the same when I run Windows Service?

My question is:

- how do I resolve this issue? Do I need to add

  ```
  _attachmentService = Container.Resolve<IAttachmentService>();

  _brxxgeService = Container.Resolve<IBrxxgeService>();

  _clRequestService = Container.Resolve<IClRequestService>();
  ```

for all of the interface services here?

- if yes, where should I add them?

Please help.

Comment: It is complaining that it cannot find a registration map for `IClEventManager`. Did you register this interface?

Comment: As you can see in `ConfigContainer` I am registering all Interface services as services will be calling `Manager` interface internally. We dont register Manager interface in Unity.

Comment: If some class depends on `IClEventManager` and you don't register it, how do you expect unity to be able to create such class?

Answer (score 1):

Better way to use continer [extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainerextension.initialize.aspx):

```
public class ModelContainerExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<IAttachmentService, AttachmentService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<IBrxxgeService, BrxxgeService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        Container.RegisterType<ICaxxxxociationService, CaxxxxociationService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());            
        Container.RegisterType<ITraxxxacityService, TraxxxcityService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
}

public partial class DClearanceService : ServiceBase
{
    private UnityContainer _container = new UnityContainer();

    public DimensionalClearanceService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ExceptionHandlingManager.InitializeExceptionManager();

        _container.AddExtension(new ModelContainerExtension());
    }
```

Why it's better? In your case you replace whole container variable, and if you made some registraions before - you'll lose it. With `AddExtension` you'll add new registrations to existing ones.